# python to C# data table via xml

Tags: c#, python, xml

Is there a way to write an xml file from python that can be read by the C# DataTable.ReadXml method?

I have written some python code that gathers information, compiles, sorts, analyzes, etc. I have another program that I'm trying to get to read in the final output of my python code. The other program uses xml files to read in the data that I am creating using the DataTable.ReadXml method. I have tried writing an xml file from python but the formatting seems to be wrong. Anyone have any tips to get the xml format to comply with this C# method?

Answer (score 0):

try using `etree` and encode the xml string to `UTF8`, then write it to file, and use it in `C#`. 
Something like this :

```
from lxml import etree
page = etree.Element('root')
doc = etree.ElementTree(page)
child1 = etree.SubElement(page, 'child1')
child2 = etree.SubElement(page, 'child2')
child1.text = 'I am child 1'
child2.text = 'I am child 1'
utf8String = etree.tostring(doc, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
print (utf8String ) #just for display
outFile = open('test.xml', 'wb')
outFile.write(utf8String)
```

Hope this was useful

Comment: I'm running 3.5 which doesn't seem to have lxml... any way to do it with cElementTree? is it just specifying that it needs to be a utf8 string? My real question is why is my formatting wrong since I'm creating an xml that *looks* identical when I open it, minus missing the declaration at the top